# Location of nodes in Omnet/Inet

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using the LinearMobility module of Inet in a compound module, I need to read the position of the node to use in the .cc code. I have looked for the answers and I came across this code:

```
cModule *host = getContainingNode(this); 
IMobility *mobility = check_and_cast<IMobility *>(host->getSubmodule("mobility"));
... = mobility->getCurrentPosition();
```

But unfortunately this code throws a run time error, probably there is something wrong with the check_and_cast because the getCurrentPosition() method for the mobility does not work. (I have also tried dynamic_cast instead of check_and_cast bust still the code throws an error ).
The error I receive is :

> 20:11:54 **** Build of configuration release for project copytic ****
>   make MODE=release all  copytic.cc In file included from copytic.cc:5:
>   In file included from
>   C:/Users/Rmin/om/inet4/src\inet/mobility/contract/IMobility.h:27:
>   C:/Users/Rmin/om/inet4/src\inet/common/geometry/common/Coord.h:307:27:
>   warning: 'inet::Coord::str' redeclared inline; 'dllimport' attribute
>   ignored [-Wignored-attributes] inline std::string Coord::str() const
>                             ^ In file included from copytic.cc:5: In file included from
>   C:/Users/Rmin/om/inet4/src\inet/mobility/contract/IMobility.h:28:
>   C:/Users/Rmin/om/inet4/src\inet/common/geometry/common/EulerAngles.h:77:33:
>   warning: 'inet::EulerAngles::str' redeclared inline; 'dllimport'
>   attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes] inline std::string
>   EulerAngles::str() const
>                                   ^ 2 warnings generated. token_m.cc Creating executable: out/clang-release//copytic.exe
>   out/clang-release//copytic.o:(.text[_ZN7omnetpp14check_and_castIPN4inet9IMobilityENS_7cModuleEEET_PT0_]+0x18):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZTIN4inet9IMobilityE'
>   out/clang-release//copytic.o:(.rdata[_ZTIPN4inet9IMobilityE]+0x18):
>   undefined reference to`typeinfo for inet::IMobility' clang++.exe:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) make: *** [Makefile:102: out/clang-release//copytic.exe]
>   Error 1
>
> 20:12:13 Build Finished (took 18s.781ms)

I also took a shot from the block of code in my source file :

[screenshot of the above-mentioned 3 lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKG76.png)

As you can see the getCurrentPosition() method does not work, and when I comment 2nd and 3rd lines of the above-mentioned 3 lines of code, simulation runs without any problems. 
This is the copytic.cc ( copytic.cc is only used to test the 3 line code in order to get the position of nodes and does not have any other purposes ) :

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <omnetpp.h>
    #include "token_m.h"
    #include "inet/mobility/contract/IMobility.h"


    using namespace omnetpp;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace inet;

class Txc1 : public cSimpleModule
{

public :
    simtime_t delay = 0.5 ;
    simtime_t delay2 = 0.5 ;
    simtime_t duration = 0.25 ;
    int maxnodes = 10 ;
    string x[10] = {"tic", "toc", "tic"} ;
    int numnodes = 2;
    int freenodeflag = 1;
    string successor ;
    string predecessor ;
    int inring = 0 ;
    string posx ;





protected:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(Txc1);

void Txc1::initialize()
{

    WATCH(x[0]);
    WATCH(x[1]);
    WATCH(x[2]);
    WATCH(x[3]);
    WATCH(successor);
    WATCH(numnodes);
    WATCH(y);
    WATCH(posx);

        Token *msgt = new Token("tok");
        msgt->setRingorder(0, "tic");
        successor="toc";
        predecessor="toc";
        cModule *target = getModuleByPath("Tictoc1.toc");
        sendDirect(msgt, delay , duration , target , "radioIn");
        inring = 1 ;

}

void Txc1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

    cModule *host = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("tec")->getSubmodule("mobility");
    IMobility *mmobility = check_and_cast<IMobility *>(host);
    Coord pos = mmobility->getCurrentPosition();



        if (strcmp("tok", msg->getName()) == 0 ) {
                Token *inv1 = new Token("tok");
                Token *inv2 = new Token("tok");
                Token *inv3 = new Token("tok");
                cModule *targetinv1 = getModuleByPath("Tictoc1.tic");
                cModule *targetinv2 = getModuleByPath("Tictoc1.toc");
                cModule *targetinv3 = getModuleByPath("Tictoc1.tec");
                sendDirect(inv1, delay , duration , targetinv1 , "radioIn");
                sendDirect(inv2, delay , duration , targetinv2 , "radioIn");
                sendDirect(inv3, delay , duration , targetinv3 , "radioIn");
            }

    }
```

Comment: Could you precise `does not work` statement - it does not compile, or it throws a runtime error? Could you edit your question and add a log that shows your problem?

Comment: @JerzyD. I edited the question as you said, do you know what the problem might be ?

Comment: Could you show copytic.cc and copytic.h?

Comment: @JerzyD. I only used copytic to test the 3 lines of code for getting the location of nodes ( and it is worth mentioning that when I comment out 2nd and 3rd lines of the 3 line code, the copytic works just fine ) .
I edited my question and included the copytic.